# Convergence of series $\sum \frac{1}{n^a\log(n)^b}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am trying to analyze the convegence of the series

$$\sum \frac{1}{n^a\log(n)^b}$$

Efforts: By using Cauchy Condensation test, the series transforms to

$$\sum {2^n\over 2^{na}n^b\log(2)^b}$$

After simplifying $$\sum {2^{n-na}\over n^b\log(2)^b}$$

Now I know exponential grows faster than the power so series converges for $n-na<0$ that is $a>1$.

If $a=1$ then series converges iff $b>1$.

Am I right?

Comment: Yes. https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C3%A9rie_de_Bertrand

Comment: @Did Are you from France Monsieur Did :)

Comment: Anyway, it happens that the WP page does not exist in English (but if you prefer to read it in Spanish or in Romanian, please help yourself...).